# upload .gpx file Streamlit Python

Tags: python, gpx, streamlit

I've made a Streamlit app using python, in which it is possible to drag and drop a gpx file.

```
import streamlit as st 
file = st.file_uploader("Upload a strava file (gpx)", type=["gpx"],accept_multiple_files=False)
```

[image]

However opening the InMemoryUploadedFile with the package gpxpy package isn't possible. Giving me a KeyError: 3655

```
import gpxpy
gpx = gpxpy.parse(file)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
import streamlit as st
import gpxpy

file = st.file_uploader("Upload a strava file (gpx)", type=["gpx"], accept_multiple_files=False)

if uploaded_file is not None:
    gpx = gpxpy.parse(uploaded_file)
```

Please also make sure both streamlit and gpxpy is updated to the latest version and the gpx file is not corrupted

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This doesn't work. My code wasn't complete, I already had the If statement in place. The problem is that it can't handle the in memory file..